# asp.net - gridview update refresh page and reload data

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a page with a gridview. When I click on edit and update, the value in the update function reverts to the value before the update. I tried adding `if(!IsPostback)` to my page_load. Now the data is updated, but after the update, the data is not bound again.

What should I do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I found my error. My binding function is called BindData(), and I was calling DataBind() by mistake.

Lesson of the day: It's not a good idea to call a function that binds data BindData()

Thank you anyway :)